# Google Cloud VM cannot have high packet/sec rate

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, rate-limiting

I have several GCP VMs running and each has a crontab to query a RESTful API every minute. For about two hours, they were all doing this just fine, when all of the sudden, all of their Packet/sec rates plummeted at the same time.  They each were at about 1000 packets/sec when this happened. They are all still running, just much much slower. Does google cloud limit this? I could not find anything in their documentation to indicate otherwise.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question which should be asked of the Customer Service department for the company you are dealing with. Please see: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746) and [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/).

Comment: You are providing no details so we can only guess. Yes, Google does rate limit some APIs. 1,000 APIs per second might be abusive for some services. Ask yourself why you need to poll 1,000 times per second and then redesign your application.

Comment: It looks like you are hitting some [quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas), could you check it when it slow down?